# How to set confign min|maxDate in frontend magento2?

Tags: magento2, calendar

have a nice date!!. In magento2 i tried set input type date and add confign min|maxDate. but is not success. Pls tell me how to set config.

this my code:

```
<input type="date" value="04-07-2016" class="type-date  hasDatepicker mage-error" max="20-07-2016" min="20-07-2011" name="date-854" aria-invalid="true">

<script>
 require(["jquery","mage/calendar", "mage/validation"],
 function($){
       var min = $(this).attr('min'),
           max = $(this).attr('max');
       $('input[type=date]').calendar({
            buttonText:"<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            singleClick : true,
            minDate: min,
            maxDate: max,
         });

    $('#contact-form').validation();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should pass date in below format.

```
<input type="date" value="04-07-2016" class="type-date  hasDatepicker mage-error" max="20-07-2016" min="20-07-2011" name="date-854" aria-invalid="true">

<script>
 require(["jquery","mage/calendar", "mage/validation"],
 function($){
       var min = new Date("June 13, 2016"),
           max = new Date("July 25,2016");
       $('input[type=date]').calendar({
            buttonText:"<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            singleClick : true,
            minDate: min,
            maxDate: max,
         });

    $('#contact-form').validation();

});
```

Comment: tks. it good work!

Comment: Working fine :)